# What's the difference between using ori and addi to initialize a value in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips

When I want to store a value in an address in MIPS, say the value 3 in $a0, I usually just use addi $a0, $0, 3. Sometimes I see people do this using ori $a0, $0, 3. Is one better than the other? What's the difference?

Comment: Personal preference :) Same effect, probably same execution time.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: They'd better have the same execution time, as that's one of the core principles of a RISC architecture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some subtle differences between the two:

`ADDI`:

- **Sign**-extends the immediate.
- Can result in integer overflow exceptions (can be avoided by using `ADDIU` instead).

`ORI`:

- **Zero**-extends the immediate.
- Not susceptible to integer overflow.