# In MIPS, is it better to use OR or ADD to combine two registers no overlapping fields?

Tags: assembly, mips

For example, if I have in $t1:

```
abcd efgh 0000 0000
```

and in $t2:

```
0000 0000 ijkl mnop
```

where a letter can be either 0 or 1.

If I want this in $t0:

```
abcd efgh ijkl mnop
```

Which of the following is better?

```
add $t0, $t1, $t2
or  $t0, $t1, $t2
```

Note: I know that a register is 32 bits, but for the sake of simplicity assume they're 16 bits.

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370558/whats-the-difference-between-using-ori-and-addi-to-initialize-a-value-in-mips   In particular, the part about overflow exceptions applies equally to your question.

Comment: @Michael why? The fields don't overlap, how could it overflow?

Comment: If the fields don't overlap why would there be overflow from addition?

Comment: Right, I just realized that.

Comment: So in your particular case neither way is "better". I would use `or` to make it clearer that I'm combining two sets of bits, but that's just my personal preference.

Comment: beyond personal preference are there any consideration for processing time?

Comment: A real MIPS processor needs one cycle for both "ADD" and "OR". So the processing time is the same.

Comment: the amount of logic touched is probably more for the add, so or would feel cleaner.  but one cycle is one cycle, they are functionally the same.  "better" is in the eye of the beholder...

Comment: An `OR` might take a couple of femto joules less energy than an `ADD`. More importantly, using an `OR` says you are manipulating bits and not doing arithmetic!

Comment: A possible superscalar MIPS core could might be able to run `or` in parallel with more things than with `add`, or with higher throughput.  This is unlikely though: they're both simple enough that all execution units could probably run either.  So I'd expect `add` and `or` to still have the same performance in any future high-performance MIPS implementation that can run more than one instruction per clock.  Actually, [r10000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R10000) already exists.  It has two integer pipelines, with an adder and logic unit on each pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Try asking, "What if there *was* overlap?"

There might not be any now, but what if something changes later so that there is overlap? Should it then behave as `add` or `or`?

On a related note, what is your intent with this? Are you trying to perform some arithmetic (use `add`)? Are you doing a logical operation (use `or`)? Are you combining flags (use `or`)? Pick the one that best expresses what your intent is with the code.

Answer (score 0):

So after doing some more research, it seems that one HAS to use OR instead of ADD. According to these links: [1](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~markhill/cs354/Fall2008/notes/MAL.instructions.html) [2](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Arithmetic_Instructions), ADD uses two's complement arithmetic so it wouldn't work if the bit labeled as a (in this case the sign bit) is 1.

Comment: If anything, two's complement makes this work. Signed addition is, if you use two's complement negatives, the same as unsigned addition. That's why it's so nice.